# Error "Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0"

Tags: java, android

Im using github template product-catalogue-android-master

When i try clone thins...the same error occur and i dont know what to do...
Im using Android studio 1.4, JRE 1.8, SDK Build 22.0.1.
Already put gradle 2.2.1 in project user/gradle/wrapper/dists/
and both gradle 2.2.1 and 2.4 in AS gradle folder

error says

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
         file:/C:/Android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         product-catalogue-android-master:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.jar
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.jar
         file:/C:/Android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.2.0/cardview-v7-22.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         product-catalogue-android-master:app:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

BUILD FAILED

What should i do next...anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update your Android Support Repository, Android Support Library**

And set

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

And

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and

`targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: open your `build.gradle`

Comment: Ty. But where is compile? And after i set others it make error "Error:(19, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'product-catalogue-android-master'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_cer7yi0qrxdbyitzpu5imss4t$_run_closure2@39e4b77e] on root project 'product-catalogue-android-master'." I try to configure this but it doesnt work...

Comment: Thank Amiya, i have got it figured out...update my repository and some changes with build.gradle clears thing out for me.